# Optimizing Sub Query Getting Last Entry Based On Group

Tags: mysql, subquery

We had a bug in our code that cached the wrong values to the `last_order_id` (expected_previous_order) column. The query I wrote properly finds the correct last order id but is too slow for our data set.

**I want to select this data into another table but I cannot because the query will take too long**

I have setup a simple example here with a smaller data set. Original table has about 170k rows.

**[SQL Fiddle of my Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9bc5c1/5)**

In the example:

- original_artwork_id is how these rows are grouped.
- order_id is the current rows order id
- actual_previous_order is the corrected last order id
- expected_previous_order is the currently stored last order id. This is the wrong value as it does not actually reference the last order id

[image: Showing that the acutal_previous_order should correspond with the previous order_id]

**EXPLAIN Results**

[image]

**EDIT**

Every time a reorder is placed a new entry is placed into the `order_artwork` table with a reference to the `original_artwork_id` and `last_order_id`.

The reference in the current data set to the `last_order_id` is wrong.

**I need to update all records to properly indicate the last order id.**

I am doing this by trying to find each artwork and joining it with the previous entry of the same `original_artwork_id`. Then I can pull the order_id from the last entry to update the current entries `last_order_id`

*Join the current row with the previous row created before the current row with the same original_artwork_id or the current row original_artwork_id = the previous rows id*

Comment: I faild to see the expected result and what is the question.

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.
 
 [**MySQL**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15371/how-do-i-get-the-execution-plan-for-a-view)
 
 [**How do I obtain a Query Execution Plan?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359702/how-do-i-obtain-a-query-execution-plan)

Comment: I dont understand you say query works ok, but then you say expected_previous_order has the wrong value. If we dont know the expected output or the logic how can we optimize the query.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. actual_previous_order contains the corrected value. The query works properly but will never complete with a larger data set. I am trying to figure out a way to optimize the subquery.  expected_previous_order is only there to illustrate that the cached value is wrong on the table. I think the fiddle is pretty clear?

Comment: Maybe is clear for you. I don't know the logic and you don't take time to explain it. So do you expect we do reverse engineering to understand what you need?

Comment: I have updated the question with an intended goal as well as an explain statement from the original table.

Comment: `I want to select this data into another table` is too broad. Explain the logic you want your query do.

Comment: I have added a more detailed explanation. Thank you.

Comment: So for the first row in your sql fiddle `{62555 |    67230 |  67012 }` is 67012 because is the closest on time to 67230 ?

Comment: Very close. So the second row id `167935` is closest in time to the first row `169039`. It isn't the closest order but the closest artwork with the same `original_artwork_id`. Then I reference that closest artwork's order id to get the `actual_previous_order`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this will be faster than your current query. But anyway.

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b06065/1)**

First you need add a new field

```
`pos` int DEFAULT 0,
```

And update your base case so can do the JOIN.

```
update `order_artwork` o
SET `original_artwork_id` = `id`
WHERE  `original_artwork_id` IS NULL;
```

> You could use `COALESCE(original_artwork_id, id)` but cant use index on that case.

Then assign a `row_number` to each order based in `original_artwork_id` and `date`

```
update `order_artwork` o
left join (
  SELECT o.id,
         @rn := if(@order_id = `original_artwork_id`,
                   @rn + 1,
                   if(@order_id := `original_artwork_id`, 1, 1)
                   ) as rn
  FROM `order_artwork` o
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @id := 0, @order_id := 0, @rn := 0) as var
  ORDER BY `original_artwork_id`,
           `created`
) b on
    o.id = b.id
set
    o.pos = b.rn;
```

Finally update the last order.

```
UPDATE `order_artwork` o
JOIN (
      SELECT o1.original_artwork_id,
             o2.order_id,
             o1.order_id as last_order_id
      FROM `order_artwork` o1
      LEFT JOIN `order_artwork` o2
        ON o1.pos = o2.pos - 1
       AND o1.original_artwork_id  = o2.`original_artwork_id`
      WHERE o2.pos IS NOT NULL 
      ) as b
 ON o.original_artwork_id = b.original_artwork_id
AND o.order_id = b.order_id
SET o.last_order_id = b.last_order_id;
```

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed response. This ended up working but I found that the created field was wrong for a lot of the data. So I created an alternate query that just finds the last order id that had the same original_artwork_id. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to know. So how much fast was? I wasn't sure if will improve the performance.

Comment: The performance on the update took around 10 minutes to complete. Everything else was under a minute.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the created time column was not reliable. So I decided to just find the last highest order id with the same original_artwork_id.

Create a table that has the corrected values

```
CREATE TABLE order_artwork_two AS 
   select 
      d1.id, 
      d1.order_id, 
      max(d2.order_id) last_order_id, 
      d1.original_artwork_id 
   from order_artwork d1
   left join order_artwork d2 
       ON d1.original_artwork_id = d2.original_artwork_id 
           and d1.order_id > d2.order_id 
   group by d1.original_artwork_id, d1.order_id;
```

Add an index to the new table. Otherwise the update would be way too slow

```
alter table order_artwork_two add primary KEY(id);
```

Update our original table.

```
update order_artwork d1 
    left join order_artwork_two d2 on d2.id = d1.id
    set d1.last_order_id = d2.last_order_id;
```